Azure Logic App In App SQL Trigger "When a row is inserted" / "When a row is modified" not working
I am trying to create an Azure Logic App workflow with SQL Trigger. The trigger that I am using is "When a row is inserted". However, the workflow is not getting triggered even after the records are inserted successfully in the table. I have followed all the pre-requisites as mentioned on the official MS documentation but it still doesn't work. Below are the details about my implementation.

Details of Logic App

Azure Logic App Type: Logic App Standard
Workflow Type: Stateful
Trigger: When a row is inserted (Not using V2)
Trigger Type: In App (built-in) since my logic app is deployed in an ASE v3
Database: SQL Server

Details of Database

Database used: SQL Server
Azure SQL / On-Premise DB: Its an On Premise SQL Server DB. The network where DB is installed is peered with the Azure Virtual Network where the Logic App is deployed and the DB is accessible.
Is able to connect to DB using Azure Logic App Work flow: Yes, I created a separate test workflow using HTTP trigger and added a SQL Action "Insert Row" to check if I am able to access the DB from the logic app and if I am able insert a record in the DB Table. This worked totally fine. The record was inserted when I sent a request to this HTTP triggered test workflow and later I added another action "Execute Query" with a simple SQL query
    Select * From Test;

to check if it fetches the records and it successfully fetched the record that was inserted in the previous step.
Is Change Tracking Enabled on the DB: Yes
Is Change Tracking Enabled on the Table: Yes
Does table has an Identity Column: Yes, it has a Integer Identity Column (1,1)
Does table has a RowVersion Column: Yes
I tried to use the other trigger "When a row is modified" as well but that too is not getting triggered.
Even after all this setup, its not working. Please let me know if I am missing anything. Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks and Regards,
Amit Anand

To trigger the logic apps for **Azure SQL/On-Prem SQL ** using SQL triggers, you need to enable CHANGE_TRACKING on both level Databse and Table . If CHANGE_TRACKING is not enabled, even if any changes is made, it won't trigger the SQL Triggers.

Note :- change tracking can be enabled on tables which has Primary Key/Any other key.

For reference check these MS Documents.

For On Prem SQL  follow these steps. Connect to an SQL database from workflows in Azure Logic Apps
Enable and Disable Change Tracking (SQL Server)

This worked for me.
I have used Azure SQL here. I have created table logic_app and enable tracking on both level.
//DATABSE LEVEL
ALTER DATABASE lasqldb
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2  DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)

//TABLE LEVEL
ALTER TABLE logic_app
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING


OUTPUT:

